# Yocto with Jethro 2.0 and meta-altera

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, intel-fpga, jethro

All, I am working on modifying the Yocto Jethro 2.0 branch with `meta-altera` layer for a custom Cyclone V SOC board, but having trouble to understand how to modify the devicetree and set the filesystem location. I believe the `dts` is located at `./tmp/work-shared/cyclone5/kernel-source/arch/arm/boot/dts/socfpga_cyclone5_sockit.dts`

But, my changes to the `dts` have little impact to the boot result. Below is the modified `dts` and console printout. Another interesting fact about the `bootargs baudrate 57600` on the console print out even thou I updated it to 115200 to match my putty setting. Have anyone experience this issue before? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include "socfpga_cyclone5.dtsi"

{
model = "Custom Project test1";
compatible = "altr,socfpga-cyclone5", "altr,socfpga";

chosen {
    bootargs = "console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mtdblock1 rw rootfstype=jffs2";
};

memory {
    name = "memory";
    device_type = "memory";
    reg = <0x0 0x40000000>; /* 1GB */
};

aliases {
    /* this allow the ethaddr uboot environmnet variable contents
     * to be added to the gmac1 device tree blob.
     */
    ethernet0 = &gmac1;
};

regulator_3_3v: vcc3p3-regulator {
    compatible = "regulator-fixed";
    regulator-name = "VCC3P3";
    regulator-min-microvolt = <3300000>;
    regulator-max-microvolt = <3300000>;
};

&gmac1 {
status = "okay";
phy-mode = "rgmii";
rxd0-skew-ps = <0>;
rxd1-skew-ps = <0>;
rxd2-skew-ps = <0>;
rxd3-skew-ps = <0>;
txen-skew-ps = <0>;
txc-skew-ps = <2600>;
rxdv-skew-ps = <0>;
rxc-skew-ps = <2000>;
 };

&gpio2 {
status = "okay";
};

&i2c1 {
status = "okay";
accel1: accelerometer@53 {
    compatible = "adi,adxl345";
    reg = <0x53>;

    interrupt-parent = <&portc>;
    interrupts = <3 2>;
};
};

&mmc0 {
vmmc-supply = <&regulator_3_3v>;
vqmmc-supply = <&regulator_3_3v>;
};

&usb1 {
status = "okay";
};

&qspi {
flash0: n25q00@0 {
    #address-cells = < 1 >; /* appended from boardinfo */
    #size-cells = < 1 >;    /* appended from boardinfo */
    compatible = "n25q00";  /* appended from boardinfo */
    reg = < 0 >;    /* appended from boardinfo */
    spi-max-frequency = < 100000000 >;  /* appended from boardinfo */

    cdns,page-size = <256>;
    cdns,block-size = <16>;
    cdns,read-delay = <4>;
    cdns,tshsl-ns = <50>;
    cdns,tsd2d-ns = <50>;
    cdns,tchsh-ns = <4>;
    cdns,tslch-ns = <4>;

    partition@qspi-boot {
        label = "Flash 0 Raw Data"; /* appended from boardinfo */
        reg = < 0x00000000 0x00800000 >;    /* appended from boardinfo */
    }; //end partition@0 (part0)

    partition@qspi-rootfs {
        label = "Flash 1 jffs2 Filesystem"; /* appended from boardinfo */
        reg = < 0x00800000 0x02000000 >;    /* appended from boardinfo */
    }; //end partition@800000 (part1)

    partition@qspi-FPGA {
        label = "FPGA Image";   /* appended from boardinfo */
        reg = < 0x02800000 0x00800000 >;    /* appended from boardinfo */
    }; //end partition@1800000 (part2)
}; //end n25q00@0 (flash0)
};
```

Console print out:

```
U-Boot SPL 2013.01.01 (Jan 09 2018 - 10:53:00)
BOARD : Altera SOCFPGA Cyclone V Board
CLOCK: EOSC1 clock 50000 KHz
CLOCK: EOSC2 clock 25000 KHz
CLOCK: F2S_SDR_REF clock 0 KHz
CLOCK: F2S_PER_REF clock 0 KHz
CLOCK: MPU clock 800 MHz
CLOCK: DDR clock 120 MHz
CLOCK: UART clock 100000 KHz
CLOCK: MMC clock 488 KHz
CLOCK: QSPI clock 400000 KHz
RESET: COLD
SDRAM: Initializing MMR registers
SDRAM: Calibrating PHY
SEQ.C: Preparing to start memory calibration
SEQ.C: CALIBRATION PASSED
SDRAM: 256 MiB
FPGA : Programming FPGA
SF: Read data capture delay calibrated to 3 (0 - 7)
SF: Detected N25Q00 with page size 65536, total: 134217728
FPGA : Programming FPGA passed
SF: Detected N25Q00 with page size 65536, total: 134217728


U-Boot 2013.01.01-00132-gd141e21-dirty (Jan 30 2018 - 22:11:47)

CPU   : Altera SOCFPGA Platform
BOARD : Altera SOCFPGA Cyclone V Board
I2C:   ready
DRAM:  256 MiB
MMC:   ALTERA DWMMC: 0
SF: Read data capture delay calibrated to 3 (2 - 5)
SF: Detected N25Q00 with page size 65536, total: 134217728
*** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Skipped ethaddr assignment due to invalid EMAC address in EEPROM
Net:   mii0
Warning: failed to set MAC address

Hit any key to stop autoboot:  0
SF: Detected N25Q00 with page size 65536, total: 134217728
## Flattened Device Tree blob at 00000100
Booting using the fdt blob at 0x00000100
reserving fdt memory region: addr=0 size=1000
Loading Device Tree to 03ff8000, end 03fffc82 ... OK

Starting kernel ...

[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.2.0-altera (yocto@yocto-VirtualBox) (gcc version 5.2.1 20151005 (Linaro GCC 5.2-2015.11-2) ) #3 SMP Mon Feb 5 00:00:28 EST 2018
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [413fc090] revision 0 (ARMv7), cr=10c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Custom Project test1
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 12 pages/cpu @cfdd1000 s17472 r8192 d23488 u49152
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 65024
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: console=ttyS0,57600 root=/dev/mtdblock1 rw rootfstype=jffs2
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 251080K/262144K available (6073K kernel code, 397K rwdata, 1560K rodata, 412K init, 136K bss, 11064K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
[    0.000000]     vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
[    0.000000]     fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
[    0.000000]     vmalloc : 0xd0800000 - 0xff000000   ( 744 MB)
[    0.000000]     lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xd0000000   ( 256 MB)
[    0.000000]     modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
[    0.000000]       .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc077c8a0   (7635 kB)
[    0.000000]       .init : 0xc077d000 - 0xc07e4000   ( 412 kB)
[    0.000000]       .data : 0xc07e4000 - 0xc0847698   ( 398 kB)
[    0.000000]        .bss : 0xc0847698 - 0xc0869950   ( 137 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=2, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Additional per-CPU info printed with stalls.
[    0.000000]  Build-time adjustment of leaf fanout to 32.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:16 nr_irqs:16 16
[    0.000000] L2C: platform modifies aux control register: 0x02060000 -> 0x32460000
[    0.000000] L2C: platform provided aux values permit register corruption.
[    0.000000] L2C: DT/platform modifies aux control register: 0x02060000 -> 0x32460000
[    0.000000] L2C-310 erratum 769419 enabled
[    0.000000] L2C-310 enabling early BRESP for Cortex-A9
[    0.000000] L2C-310 full line of zeros enabled for Cortex-A9
[    0.000000] L2C-310 dynamic clock gating enabled, standby mode enabled
[    0.000000] L2C-310 cache controller enabled, 8 ways, 512 kB
[    0.000000] L2C-310: CACHE_ID 0x410030c9, AUX_CTRL 0x46460001
[    0.000000] clocksource: timer1: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 38225208935 ns
[    0.000020] sched_clock: 32 bits at 50MHz, resolution 20ns, wraps every 42949672950ns
[    0.000529] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.000614] Calibrating delay loop... 795.44 BogoMIPS (lpj=3977216)
[    0.089356] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.089753] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.089779] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.091645] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.091764] ftrace: allocating 20134 entries in 60 pages
[    0.180031] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.181784] Setting up static identity map for 0x8280 - 0x82d8
[    0.269438] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.269832] Brought up 2 CPUs
[    0.269903] SMP: Total of 2 processors activated (1590.88 BogoMIPS).
[    0.269927] CPU: All CPU(s) started in SVC mode.
[    0.272542] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.286937] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 30 variant 9 rev 4
[    0.288114] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.294492] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.294798] fpga bridge driver
[    0.300623] DMA: preallocated 256 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.320507] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.320605] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.323286] altera_hps2fpga_bridge soc:fpgabridge@0: fpga bridge [hps2fpga] registered as device hps2fpga
[    0.323363] altera_hps2fpga_bridge soc:fpgabridge@0: init-val not specified
[    0.324051] altera_hps2fpga_bridge soc:fpgabridge@1: fpga bridge [lwhps2fpga] registered as device lwhps2fpga
[    0.324097] altera_hps2fpga_bridge soc:fpgabridge@1: init-val not specified
[    0.324668] altera_hps2fpga_bridge soc:fpgabridge@2: fpga bridge [fpga2hps] registered as device fpga2hps
[    0.324705] altera_hps2fpga_bridge soc:fpgabridge@2: init-val not specified
[    0.387198] FPGA Mangager framework driver
[    0.388702] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.390250] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.390483] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.390741] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.391508] soc:usbphy@0 supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.395259] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.395334] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.395458] PTP clock support registered
[    0.403399] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer1
[    0.523673] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.526153] TCP established hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.526266] TCP bind hash table entries: 2048 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.526435] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 2048 bind 2048)
[    0.526992] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.527193] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.528072] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.529822] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.529868] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.529885] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.529903] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.532124] hw perfevents: Failed to parse /soc/pmu/interrupt-affinity[0]
[    0.532326] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a9 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.532696] armv7-pmu arm-pmu: PMU:CTI successfully enabled for 2 cores
[    0.536708] futex hash table entries: 512 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.571669] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.572004] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.572030] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.572252] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/W].
[    0.573182] jffs2: version 2.2. (NAND) © 2001-2006 Red Hat, Inc.
[    0.575934] io scheduler noop registered (default)
[    0.596987] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 2 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.602276] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    0.602591] ffc02000.serial0: ttyS0 at MMIO 0xffc02000 (irq = 41, base_baud = 3125000) is a 16550A
[    1.845377] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.855038] ffc03000.serial1: ttyS1 at MMIO 0xffc03000 (irq = 42, base_baud = 3125000) is a 16550A
[    1.875914] altera_fpga_manager ff706000.fpgamgr: fpga manager [Altera FPGA Manager] registered as minor 0
[    1.902228] brd: module loaded
[    1.914601] CAN device driver interface
[    1.925629] stmmac - user ID: 0x10, Synopsys ID: 0x37
[    1.935943]  Ring mode enabled
[    1.942079]  DMA HW capability register supported
[    1.951153]  Enhanced/Alternate descriptors
[    1.959850]  Enabled extended descriptors
[    1.967892]  RX Checksum Offload Engine supported (type 2)
[    1.978840]  TX Checksum insertion supported
[    1.987369]  Enable RX Mitigation via HW Watchdog Timer
[    2.002094] libphy: stmmac: probed
[    2.008917] eth0: No PHY found
[    2.042941] stmmac - user ID: 0x10, Synopsys ID: 0x37
[    2.053143]  Ring mode enabled
[    2.059241]  DMA HW capability register supported
[    2.068295]  Enhanced/Alternate descriptors
[    2.077060]  Enabled extended descriptors
[    2.085080]  RX Checksum Offload Engine supported (type 2)
[    2.096020]  TX Checksum insertion supported
[    2.104540]  Enable RX Mitigation via HW Watchdog Timer
[    2.118454] libphy: stmmac: probed
[    2.125299] eth0: No PHY found
[    2.162610] dwc2 ffb40000.usb: Bad value for GSNPSID: 0x00000000
[    2.177122] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.189833] i2c /dev entries driver
[    2.200166] Synopsys Designware Multimedia Card Interface Driver
[    2.213581] dw_mmc ff704000.dwmmc0: IDMAC supports 32-bit address mode.
[    2.227064] dw_mmc ff704000.dwmmc0: Using internal DMA controller.
[    2.239475] dw_mmc ff704000.dwmmc0: Version ID is 240a
[    2.249920] dw_mmc ff704000.dwmmc0: DW MMC controller at irq 31, 32 bit host data width, 1024 deep fifo
[    2.280984] mmc_host mmc0: Bus speed (slot 0) = 244140Hz (slot req 400000Hz, actual 244140HZ div = 0)
[    2.311046] dw_mmc ff704000.dwmmc0: 1 slots initialized
[    2.322577] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.335292] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.346497] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.355131] oprofile: using arm/armv7-ca9
[    2.366826] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    2.378848] sit: IPv6 over IPv4 tunneling driver
[    2.390352] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.399434] NET: Registered protocol family 15
[    2.408341] can: controller area network core (rev 20120528 abi 9)
[    2.420967] NET: Registered protocol family 29
[    2.429860] can: raw protocol (rev 20120528)
[    2.438436] can: broadcast manager protocol (rev 20120528 t)
[    2.449765] can: netlink gateway (rev 20130117) max_hops=1
[    2.461493] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[    2.470123] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.479141] ThumbEE CPU extension supported.
[    2.487754] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    2.511539] ttyS0 - failed to request DMA
[    2.520589] List of all partitions:
[    2.527712] 0100            8192 ram0  (driver?)
[    2.536990] 0101            8192 ram1  (driver?)
[    2.546235] No filesystem could mount root, tried:  jffs2
[    2.557086] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
[    2.573571] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 4.2.0-altera #3
[    2.586397] Hardware name: Altera SOCFPGA
[    2.594605] [<c0017db4>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0013ae8>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[    2.610115] [<c0013ae8>] (show_stack) from [<c0579348>] (dump_stack+0x80/0x90)
[    2.624525] [<c0579348>] (dump_stack) from [<c05770e8>] (panic+0xac/0x1fc)
[    2.638290] [<c05770e8>] (panic) from [<c077e440>] (mount_block_root+0x254/0x268)
[    2.653216] [<c077e440>] (mount_block_root) from [<c077e66c>] (mount_root+0x12c/0x134)
[    2.668998] [<c077e66c>] (mount_root) from [<c077e7ec>] (prepare_namespace+0x178/0x1c0)
[    2.684953] [<c077e7ec>] (prepare_namespace) from [<c077df58>] (kernel_init_freeable+0x274/0x284)
[    2.702638] [<c077df58>] (kernel_init_freeable) from [<c0575e38>] (kernel_init+0x1c/0xf8)
[    2.718936] [<c0575e38>] (kernel_init) from [<c000fb28>] (ret_from_fork+0x14/0x2c)
[    2.734035] CPU1: stopping
[    2.739449] CPU: 1 PID: 17 Comm: kworker/u4:1 Not tainted 4.2.0-altera #3
[    2.752965] Hardware name: Altera SOCFPGA
[    2.761017] Workqueue: kmmcd mmc_rescan
[    2.768713] [<c0017db4>] (unwind_backtrace) from [<c0013ae8>] (show_stack+0x20/0x24)
[    2.784151] [<c0013ae8>] (show_stack) from [<c0579348>] (dump_stack+0x80/0x90)
[    2.798549] [<c0579348>] (dump_stack) from [<c0016454>] (handle_IPI+0x214/0x230)
[    2.813290] [<c0016454>] (handle_IPI) from [<c00094b4>] (gic_handle_irq+0x68/0x6c)
[    2.828376] [<c00094b4>] (gic_handle_irq) from [<c0014700>] (__irq_svc+0x40/0x54)
[    2.843280] Exception stack(0xcf969d88 to 0xcf969dd0)
[    2.853358] 9d80:                   000000d5 ffffffff 00000f2c c02dbcc8 c07e6100 ffff8beb
[    2.869645] 9da0: 0010624c cfaaf704 cfaaf618 c081ec38 cf00d405 cf969df4 cf969df8 cf969dd0
[    2.885928] 9dc0: c0424ec0 c02dbcf8 20000113 ffffffff
[    2.896067] [<c0014700>] (__irq_svc) from [<c02dbcf8>] (__loop_delay+0x0/0x10)
[    2.910506] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

modifying sources in the `./tmp/` directory doesn't have any effect, as those changes will be overwritten by the next `do_fetch` from bitbake.

AFAIK the best way to modify an in-tree dts file is to add a patch using a `.bbappend` file for the kernel. Something like the following:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRC_URI += "file://0001-my-dts-changes.patch"
```

For more details on that please take a look at the Yoctoproject Kernel Manual:: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/kernel-manual/kernel-manual.html